# Can .NET web services with wsHttpBinding be consumed by python

Tags: c#, python, webservice-client, wshttpbinding, basichttpbinding

I got a problem because I have a web service with wsHttpBinding:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="BindingTest.IService1" />
```

I can't get my python code call it, every time that I try to call I receive this error message:

```
Exception: (400, u'Bad Request')
```

After investigate a lot and searching in internet I made it work just specifying to my Web Service to have basicHttpBinding:

```
<endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="BindingTest.IService1" />
```

In this way I could call the web service from python code!

Now my problem is another: I can't really modify the web service, I could try locally but I don't have the permission to modify it.

So, is there some way to specify in python to make a "wsHttpBinding" request?

This is my actual code:

```
import logging
from suds.client import Client
import sys
from suds.sax.element import Element

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
logger = logging.getLogger('suds.transport.http')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG), handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)

client =Client('Service_URL')
client.set_options(headers={'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'})
result = client.service.RouteDocument('Input')
```

Comment: same problem!! got any solution?

Comment: Nop, just change the API type to Rest API and I had no problems

Comment: Moving to REST API is recommended anyway since WCF will not be supported in future releases of .NET.

Comment: Hi @Peter I know, but I have some service that are still in .Net and are the only one I couldn't automatize